# Interpreting SDM results

Tags: google-earth-engine

I am using a SDM (random forest) in GEE. The prediction works fine and as a result I get HSI values and the typical metrics (AUC etc) as well as variable importances of my predictor variables. However, I would like to know not only the strength of the correlation of my predictors but also the direction of correlation. E.g if high or low elevation is influencing my model.

Is there a way to calculate that in the GEE ? Do I need to export my data to R ?

Help is very much appreciated!